# how to check if image is really jpeg or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, encoding, hex

I have applied a code to check if image extension really matches with image content.
I checked the initial two values of raw image and matched them with [0xFF, 0xD8] to find if it is jpg or jpeg image.

It is working fine with jpg image ..but not working for JPEG format.
Wikipedia has given same these two initial encodings for both jpeg and jpg.
but for jpeg, I am receiving [137,80]

```
$scope.checkContentOfImage=function(file){
var deferred =$q.defer();

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend  = function (e) {
    var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
    let flag=true;
    let pattern=[0xFF, 0xD8];
    for(let i=0 ; i< 2; i++){
        if(arr[i]!=pattern[i]){
            flag=false;
            break;
    }}
if(flag){
    deferred.resolve("success");
}
else{
    deferred.reject("not image file");
}

}
reader.onerror=function(){
    deferred.reject("failuer in checking content");
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
return deferred.promise;

}
```

How can I check for jpeg encoding format? This is working fine for jpg

Comment: The two filename extensions mean the same thing; it's all JPEG.

Comment: 137,80 == 0x89 0x50 == PNG header - the file is a  PNG.

Comment: Then why it is converted intp [137,80] for jpeg extension?

Comment: Presumably its a PNG with an incorrect extension.

Comment: Please also note that just because a few bytes are right at the beginning of a file it does not mean that the rest matches any given specification.